# I want my Database to not fill the RAM. What to do with images that are currently not being viewed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ram

**What does my program do?**

As at 05 May 2021

This program was developed with the language VB.Net, the .NET framework 4.8 and with Visual Studio 2019 CE. The point of this program is to run a rudimentary database. The view is similar to a classic Internet forum—there are threads, in the threads there are different numbers of postings and in each post there are different numbers of pictures and long texts. If the thread is selected using the ComboBox, all posts with their images and texts are displayed one below the other. When you click on a specific post, only *its* images are displayed. Since the database is only intended for the company's products, it was decided not to use categories (e.g. images vs. videos vs. offtopic because it doesn't make any sense) and sub-categories (e.g. electrical vs. wood products).

When the program is closed, you will be asked whether the data should be saved. (still in the beta version). These data are read in when the program is loaded. If images are not found, their paths will be displayed in a window.

The user also has the option of searching through all threads and viewing the results with various sorting options. In this case, only the posts found are listed in the ListBox, and here, too, the user can select individual posts and have them displayed enlarged.

The program reads in the user data when it starts. A user can log in and, depending on his role, has certain power to make decisions. A “normal” user can create threads and posts, but only an administrator or moderator can edit and delete posts; and block a user. If you are not logged in or if you are locked, you can only read threads and posts.

The number of contributions is counted for each user. In the future, it should be possible to give a user stars.

**About the classes**

There is the `Form1.vb` class, and three other important classes: `Class_Forum`, `Class_Post` and `Class_Thread`. There is also the `Class_User` class. If a new post is created, this instance of `Class_Post` is added to a `List(of Class_Post)`, which is located in `Class_Thread` (“The thread knows which posts it has”). `Class_Post` has a member ‘Made_by’, which is an instance of the `Class_Users` (“Every post knows which user made it”). `Class_Post` contains the member ‚Bilder‘ (=Images), which is a `List(Of Bitmap)`.     That is, every instance of `class_post` has got a List(of Bitmap).

There are also several forms for 1) editing, deleting posts, 2) for blocking or unblocking users, 3) for displaying enlarged images, 4) for logging in, 5) for displaying when images are not loading found, 6) to open the thread, 7) to post.

When the program is started, i.e. when data is read in, the thread instances and post instances are created.

[image: class diagramm]

**To do list:
1.)**
I would like, however, that only the images are in the RAM, which belong to the thread selected with the combobox1. My question is: *Do I have to dispose all unnecessary images and read them in again* when required? Do we get that built in?

This is my Code to load the data from the formatted txt file. I have a feeling, somewhere in here, or immediately after here, I have to do something.

```
Private Sub Daten_laden()
        Dim Pfad As String 'file path
        Using OFD1 As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD1.Title = "Textdatei auswählen"
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Textdatei", ".txt"))
            OFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
            Dim Result As CommonFileDialogResult
            Me.Invoke(Sub() Result = OFD1.ShowDialog())
            If Result = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Pfad = OFD1.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Dim Pruef_Anzahl_Posts_in_dem_Thread As Integer = 0 'Check number of posts in the thread 
        Dim Liste_mit_den_Pfaden As List(Of String) 'List with file paths
        Dim Liste_mit_den_Bildern As List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap)
        'read all Text
        Dim RAT() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Pfad, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        Pfade_von_nicht_gefundenen_Bildern = New List(Of String) ' Paths of not found images

        For i As Integer = 3 To RAT.Length - 2 Step 1
            Liste_mit_allen_Threads.Add(New Class_Thread(RAT(i)))
            Me.Invoke(Sub() RaiseEvent Es_wurde_ein_neuer_Thread_eroeffnet()) 'A new thread has been opened
            Pruef_Anzahl_Posts_in_dem_Thread = CInt(RAT(i + 1))

            For j As Integer = (i + 2) To RAT.Length - 2 Step 1
                Liste_mit_den_Pfaden = New List(Of String)
                Liste_mit_den_Bildern = New List(Of Bitmap)
                Dim Index As Integer
                Dim Die_ID_des_Nutzers_der_den_Post_erstellt_hat As ULong = CULng(RAT(j + 4)) 'The ID of the user who created the post
                For u As Integer = 0 To alle_Nutzer_Liste.Count - 1 Step 1
                    If alle_Nutzer_Liste(u).ID = Die_ID_des_Nutzers_der_den_Post_erstellt_hat Then
                        Index = u
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                Dim neuerPost As New Class_Post(RAT(j), RAT(j + 1), CUShort(RAT(j + 2)), Liste_mit_den_Bildern, CDate(RAT(j + 3)), Liste_mit_den_Pfaden, alle_Nutzer_Liste(Index))
               'how many threads are there already                
                Dim wie_viele_Threads_gibt_es_bereits As Integer = Liste_mit_allen_Threads.Count
                Liste_mit_allen_Threads(wie_viele_Threads_gibt_es_bereits - 1).Posts_in_diesem_Thread.Add(neuerPost)
                ' Set the index to the last possible one in the ComboBox. This causes the program to run into the Selected Index event and SI becomes the selected index. 
                Me.Invoke(Sub() ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Liste_mit_allen_Threads.Count - 1)
                j += 5
                Do
                    Liste_mit_den_Pfaden.Add(RAT(j))
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(RAT(j)) Then
                        Liste_mit_den_Bildern.Add(New Bitmap(RAT(j)))
                    Else
                        Pfade_von_nicht_gefundenen_Bildern.Add(RAT(j))
                    End If
                    j += 1
                Loop Until RAT(j) = "#" ' Marker: a post is over 
                If RAT(j + 1) = "" AndAlso RAT(j + 2) = "" Then ' A new thread is marked with 2 blank lines one below the other.
                    i = (j + 2)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Me.Invoke(Sub() alle_Posts_in_diesem_Thread_anzeigen()) 'show all posts in this thread
        If Pfade_von_nicht_gefundenen_Bildern.Count > 0 Then ' In Case something went wrong
            Using FBNG As New Form_Bild_nicht_gefunden
                FBNG.Datei_anzeigen(Pfade_von_nicht_gefundenen_Bildern)
                
                FBNG.ShowDialog()
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```

On this image, the thread is being switched using the combobox which changes the variable `SI` which I use often. In this example, the thread `Caucasian` contains 1 post which contains 2 images. **Which means, (still in this moment) I don't need images form `shepherds` thread**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Harald Coppoolse,
I thank you for your detailed and understandable answer. Admittedly, I have to look at and learn those SQL (Light) and Entity procedures.

For now, I've temporarily made sure that I only load the pictures that are shown and dispose all the others. I coded this as follows:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> (-1) Then
            SI = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
            If Programm_fertig_geladen Then
                Load_the_pictures_only_when_shown_and_free_up_memory_after_an_Image_is_not_needed()
            End If
            alle_Posts_in_diesem_Thread_anzeigen()
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub Load_the_pictures_only_when_shown_and_free_up_memory_after_an_Image_is_not_needed()
        For g As Integer = 0 To Liste_mit_allen_Threads.Count - 1 Step 1
            If g <> SI Then 'Diese Bilder verwerfen
                For i As Integer = 0 To Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread.Count - 1 Step 1
                    For j As Integer = 0 To Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).Bilder.Count - 1 Step 1
                        Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).Bilder(j).Dispose()
                        Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).BoolArray(j) = False
                    Next
                    Dim CNT As Integer = Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).Bilder.Count
                    For z As Integer = (CNT - 1) To 0 Step -1
                        Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).Bilder.RemoveAt(z)
                    Next

                Next
            Else 'Diese Bilder laden
                'für jeden Post
                For i As Integer = 0 To Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread.Count - 1 Step 1
                    'die Bilder in dem Post
                    For j As Integer = 0 To Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).Pfade_der_Bilder.Count - 1 Step 1
                        Dim neu_geladenes_Bild As New Bitmap(Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).Pfade_der_Bilder(j))
                        If Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).BoolArray(j) = False Then
                            Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).Bilder.Add(neu_geladenes_Bild)
                            Liste_mit_allen_Threads(g).Posts_in_diesem_Thread(i).BoolArray(j) = True
                        End If
                        'End Using
                    Next
                Next
            End If
        Next
        
    End Sub
```

I built a Boolean array into the `Class_Post`, which has as many members as there are images and paths in the post. The purpose of this is to make sure that I remember which pictures are there and which are not.

- When disposing of the images of a post, the respective array member is set to `false`.
- When reloading the images of a post, the respective array member is set to `True`.
- `Dispose` alone is not enough, because funnily enough, the place in the `List(of Bitmap)` remains occupied. You also have to completely delete the picture with `RemoveAt`, but in a **backward** running for loop, because the list gets smaller during the deletion. ;)
- `Using` cannot not be used.

Answer (score 3):

It is not wise to keep all data in RAM. When your database grows, there will be a time that there is too much data.

To overcome this problem, people invented databases: the data is saved on a disk, and only the data that you request is put into memory. Smart databases will keep important data and often used values in memory, to minimize the request time.

If I look at your program, it seems that you only have to change the display after operator input. Operator input is relatively slow: you're a good typist if you can type more than 3 character per second. Usually the response time after operator input is not a problem: if you get the data within half a second, no one will complain.

For a modern computer half a second is enough time to examine a million records. In your application a database won't be a problem.

So my advice would be: start using a database and load only the data that is needed right now, instead of reading all data at startup. Only if you experience long request times, consider to load data that you expect you will need very soon.

Alas, to use a database you will need to learn something new: at least how to structure a databases. If I look at your tables, I have the impression that you already mastered this. Furthermore you'll have to learn how to add / query / update / remove data. This is usually done using SQL or software that supports LINQ, like entity framework.

It seems to me that your queries are quite limited in number: you won't have hundreds of different queries. If you already know SQL, and you don't think you need to know entity framework in the near future, I would go for accessing the database using SQL.

If you don't know SQL very much, or if you need to do an awful lot of different queries, consider to access the database using LINQ. This requires entity framework.

If you haven't got a database already, my first shot would be to use SQLight: a database in one file, fast enough for your application.

If you hide properly that you use SQLight, migrating to a smarter database if the need arises won't require a big change in your application.

```
class Repository
{
    public long AddPost(Post post) {...} // add Post to the database, returns the Id
    public long AddUser(User user) {...}
    ...

    // fetch all Posts of a User:
    public User FetchUserWithHisPosts(int userId);

    // fetch Posts of a User after a certain data:
    public User FetchUserWithHisPosts(int userId, DateTime startDate);

    ...
}
```

A Repository is some kind of warehouse: all you know is that you can store items in it, and later retrieve them, even after your computer is restarted.

The Repository hides how it does this: the constructor might load everything in memory (like your current application), it could also be that the repository uses SQLight, or a smarter database, or even Entity Framework.

A good way to migrate would be to first translate your current application such that everyone only accesses the data using the Repository. The Repository accesses your "in-memory data" which is in a separate class that is loaded at startup.

Later you can change the repository such that it doesn't use the "in-memory data" anymore, but accesses the database: users of your repository won't have to change.

### About loading pictures

No, you don't have to load all pictures at startup. It will be fast enough to load the pictures only when shown: after all, you won't be showing 1000 pictures on the screen at once.

As a picture uses a lot of memory, it is wise to `Dispose()` the picture as soon as you don't need it anymore:

```
Image GetImage(long imageId)
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();
    return repository.GetImageById(imageId); 
}

void DisposeImage(Image image)
{
    image.Dispose();
}
```

You hide how you Load the image, and how you free up memory after an Image is not needed anymore. This makes it easier to change this, might the need arise later. It also makes your code easier to read and to unit test.